# How to join two unrelated entities using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, entity

I have two tables -  one containing Address and another containing Photographs. The only common field between them is the PersonID. These were mapped to two POJO Classes Address and Photo. I was able to fetch details in these tables by creating criteria and adding restrictions on the fields . How should we write a join on the two tables. Is it possible to get the result as two objects -Address and Photo.

I want to do a left join so that i can get records of persons without photos as well.
I have read that this is possible only using hql but Can this be done using criterias as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily write HQL query that will return result as two objects using Theta Join (as Adrian noted). Here is an example:

```
String queryText = "select address, photo from Address address, Photo photo " 
                 + " where address.personID=photo.personId";
List<Object[]> rows = session.createQuery(queryText).list();

for (Object[] row: rows) {
    System.out.println(" ------- ");
    System.out.println("Address object: " + row[0]);
    System.out.println("Photo object: " + row[1]);
}
```

As you can see query returns list of Object[] arrays that represents each fetched row. First element of this array will contain one obejct and second element - another.

**EDIT:**

In case of left join I think you need to use native SQL query (not HQL query). Here how you can do this:

```
String queryText = "select address.*, photo.* from ADDRESS address 
                    left join PHOTO photo on (address.person_id=photo.person_id)";

List<Object[]> rows = sess.createSQLQuery(queryText)
                          .addEntity("address", Address.class)
                          .addEntity("photo", Photo.class)
                          .list();
```

This should work for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the example but can we do a left join...i have tried using "Address left join photo" but the following error occurs... "outer or full join must be followed by path expression"

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer and add example for left join. I think this should work for you.

Comment: @dimas can we use hql in left join

Comment: Would it be possible to alter the native SQL-query so that it would result a list of photos per address if multiple photos was linked to address?

Answer (score 15):

Basically, you have two options:

1. Since Hibernate 5.1, you can use [ad-hoc joins](http://in.relation.to/2016/02/10/hibernate-orm-510-final-release/) for unrelated entities.

   ```
    Tuple postViewCount = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select p as post, count(pv) as page_views " +
        "from Post p " +
        "left join PageView pv on p.slug = pv.slug " +
        "where p.title = :title " +
        "group by p", Tuple.class)
    .setParameter("title", "High-Performance Java Persistence")
    .getSingleResult();
   ```
2. Prior to Hibernate 5.1, you could only use theta-style joins. However, a theta-style join is equivalent to an equijoin, hence you can only emulate INNER JOINs not OUTER JOINs.

   ```
    List<Tuple> postViewCount = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select p as post, count(pv) as page_views " +
        "from Post p, PageView pv " +
        "where p.title = :title and " +
        "      ( p.slug = pv.slug ) " +
        "group by p", Tuple.class)
    .setParameter("title", "Presentations")
    .getResultList();
   ```

Comment: Is there any alternative for previous version. I am using hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9 which gives me "path expected for Join!" error

Comment: You can use theta-style joins.

Answer (score 5):

Finally after 12 years the Hibernate team has [implemented such a feature](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16)

From [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join):

The FROM clause can also contain explicit relationship joins using the join keyword. These joins can be either inner or left outer style joins.

```
List<Person> persons = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select distinct pr " +
    "from Person pr " +
    "join pr.phones ph " +
    "where ph.type = :phoneType", Person.class )
.setParameter( "phoneType", PhoneType.MOBILE )
.getResultList();


List<Person> persons = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select distinct pr " +
    "from Person pr " +
    "left join pr.phones ph " +
    "where ph is null " +
    "   or ph.type = :phoneType", Person.class )
.setParameter( "phoneType", PhoneType.LAND_LINE )
.getResultList();
```

Or you can use `WITH` and `ON` keywords. A remark on those

> The important distinction is that in the generated SQL the conditions
>   of the WITH/ON clause are made part of the ON clause in the generated
>   SQL, as opposed to the other queries in this section where the
>   HQL/JPQL conditions are made part of the WHERE clause in the generated
>   SQL.

Example

```
List<Object[]> personsAndPhones = session.createQuery(
    "select pr.name, ph.number " +
    "from Person pr " +
    "left join pr.phones ph with ph.type = :phoneType " )
.setParameter( "phoneType", PhoneType.LAND_LINE )
.list();
```

I am currently eager to try the new feature.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I think this is not an `unrelated entity`. These are related through the `phones` property. Could you provide the entity class?

Answer (score 3):

Joining two unrelated entities are possible in Hibernate 5.1.

Eg :

```
select objA from ObjectA objA   
JOIN ObjectB objB on objB.variable = objA.variable    
where objA.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

1. HQL
2. Join on fields that you haven't modeled as relationships
3. Left Join

***(During the time the question was first asked and this answer was given)*** Hibernate supports Theta Join which allows you to do 1 & 2. However, only inner join is available for theta join style.

Personally I would recommend you to model proper relationships, so you just need 1 & 3 which is well-supported in HQL.

(Another answer actually provided an update on new Hibernate feature that provides such feature, that you may simply refer to)

Comment: Wonder why it was down voted. The answer is in fact correct (even the accepted answer base on this) and I did give example just because it is trivial to find in given the key information provided. And the left join requirement is given later

Comment: @Ismael I will rephrase it a bit but I don't think what I said is incomplete: There is no proper way using HQL to achieve what is requested by OP.  Theta join is the closest he can get but as it is not doing what he what, I just won't bother giving example on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to have a class containing those classes you want to join to have them all together.

But if you are joining these tables just for some occasional purposes, you can use criteria and manually load data from each table and put them together. (and yes, you can have these tables' data separately if for Address and Photo there are two separate classes and tables)

Comment: martin can you please elaborate a little on this. How do I create a class for this scenario?

Comment: Create a class with the attributes you have in your join. This class should be bound to a database table with the name which holds the relation between your entities. (Here lets call them `address_photo_rel` table). Therefore, when hibernate is creating tables for you classes, this join table is also created. _If you do not do that, and since you have a relation between your entities (here `address` and `photo`), the hibernate will eventually create that table, but you have no control over that, since you do not have a class for it._