# hibernate extra clause on join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Long time ago, I built a web application in java with servlets and jsps and now, I would like to re-create it using the frameworks spring and hibernate.

However, I have some difficulties with hibernate to do some queries containing "joins" with special clauses and I would have 2 questions.

I give you a fictional example, let's imagine a rally race results application :

first imagine 3 tables :

- race (id,name)
- driver (id, name)
- result(id_race,id_driver,final_position)

the Entity Race has a many to many association with the Entity Race and has a Set of Drivers.

Now, I would like to make in hql a query returning the same results as the results returned by this sql query :

```
select ra.*,d.name from race as ra left outer join result as re on re.id_race=ra.id and re.final_pos=1  inner join driver as d on d.id=re.id_driver
```

**1st question**, In hql, how can I add this specific clause (final_pos=1) on my join ?

I have read about the keyword "with" but it doesn't work with fetch and I need eager loading for this information.

then, I have tried the "filter" annotation and that works.  but not completely in fact....

If I query the entity Race, I get (if he already exists) the winner of the race

But now,if I add another table, for example, the table "rally_stage"(id,name,id_race).  A race contains several stages and one stage is linked to one and only one race.

If now, I query the Entity RallyStage, the filter is ignored and the query returns all the drivers having participated to the race (and not only the winner)

I know that I need to enable the filter in my code and I do it, but do you know why it works when I query the Entity Race (which contains the filter) but why it doesn't work when I query the Entity RallyStage which is linked to only one Race.

Do you think that it is possible that different  "hibernate sessions" are used to  return my results (RallyStage, Race and winners) and so, the filter is not applied on all these different sessions.

If it is the case, How can I solve it because I get the drivers just in calling the property "drivers" of my Entity Race.

**2nd question** : As I am sure that there is only one winner for a race(or no winner at all if the race has not  been raced yet), I would like to sort my results on the driver name.

sql example :

```
select ra.*,d.name from race as ra left outer join result as re on re.id_race=ra.id and re.final_pos=1  inner join driver as d on d.id=re.id_driver order by d.name
```

As drivers is a Set in the Entity Race, so I cannot sort this property.  the annotation @orderby allows to sort the set contained in the entity "Race", but it doesn't sort the list of races. (which is what I want to do).

Any ideas?

I would really appreciate if you could help me  about these 2 problems which really drive me nuts.

I hope that my explanations are not too cloudy and my apologies for my approximative english.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**1st question:**

Why don't you move that second condition to the where clause like this

```
select ra.*,d.name 
from race as ra 
left outer join result as re on re.id_race=ra.id 
inner join driver as d on d.id=re.id_driver
where re.final_pos=1
```

This can be done in HQL, if this doesn't fit you, you can also try a Theta join like in this example: [How to join two unrelated entities using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822302/joins-on-unrelated-table-using-hibernate)

**2nd question:**

Here you could either create a different HQL query that will retrieve the list already sorted by driver name for you. Or use that set you got and sort it in Java directly.