# HQL join on unrelated tables

Tags: java, sql, orm, hql

I have two reference tables that I am trying to do a join on but am having an issue doing so with HQL.

```
public class Person {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  // mutators
}

public class Audit{
  private int id;
  private String person_id;
  private String status;
  // mutators
}
```

Can anyone explain how I might write an HQL query to join the Person object to the Audit object?

**UPDATE**
I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824256/1413756) answers my question.

Example HQL looking for Audit logs by person name:

```
SELECT a from PERSON p, AUDIT a WHERE p.id=a.person_id and p.name like '%:name%'
```

Comment: can you tell us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public class Person
{
  private int id;
  private String name;
}

public class Audit
{
 private int id;
 private Person person;
 private String status;
}
```

write HQL..

```
   public List<Audit> getAuditData(int id){
   String sql = "from Audit where person.id=?";
   return getHibernateTemplate().find(sql,
            new Integer[] { new Integer(id) });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  The only piece that is missing is having the ability to search by the name of the person (`p.name like (:name%)`)