# In Hibernate, how do I join when the relationship is not mapped?

Tags: hibernate

Here is an excerpt of my domain model, the text version of which is "I have Contracts, Clients, Clients on Contracts, and Invoices.  Invoices can either be linked directly to a Client, or to a Contract".

```
<class name="Invoice">
  <many-to-one class="Contract" />
  <many-to-one class="Client" />
</class>

<class name="Contract">
  <set table="ContractClient" fetch="select" lazy="true">
    <one-to-many class="ContractClient" />
  </set>
</class>

<class name="ContractClient">
  <many-to-one class="Contract" fetch="select" />
  <many-to-one class="Client" cascade="none" fetch="select" />
</class>

<class name="Client">
  <set table="ContractClient" fetch="select" lazy="true">
    <one-to-many class="ContractClient" />
  </set>
</class>
```

I am interested in obtaining the list of Invoices belonging to a Client, including both the directly linked Invoices, and those on Contracts on which the Client is a party.   I have the following (which works):

```
return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Invoice.class)
    .createAlias("contract", "contract", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
    .createAlias("contract.contractClients", "contractClient", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.eq("client.id", id),
        Restrictions.eq("contractClient.client.id", id)))
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .list();
}
```

However, there's big performance issues with the generated SQL, as (not shown) Contract has a number of 1:1 tables and lots of fetch=join lookups. Also, the OR sort of kills it.  So, I'm already taking the approach of separate queries for the two types (Invoices directly linked to Clients, and Invoices linked to Clients through the Contract).  I'm having trouble coming up with the second piece.

I'd like to avoid joining through Contract because of the explosion in JOINS and selected columns. If I were writing this in SQL myself, I'd use:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Invoice i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ContractClient c ON i.contractId=c.contractId 
WHERE 
    c.clientId=?
```

But, I don't have a Hibernate mapping between Invoice and ContractClient, so I either have to go through Contract (which I don't want), or do this (which produces a sub-select):

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ContractClient.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("client.id", id))
    .setProjection(Projections.property("contract"));
return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Invoice.class)
    .add(Property.forName("contract").in(detachedCriteria))
    .list();
```

producing:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Invoice this_ 
WHERE
    this_.contractId IN (   SELECT
                            this_.contractId AS y0_ 
                        FROM
                            ContractClient this_ 
                        WHERE
                            this_.contractClientId=?)
```

Is there a way to get Hibernate to generate the more direct JOIN?

Comment: I would just use a native query using entityManager.[createNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String))

Comment: Yes, it's called [Theta join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822302/joins-on-unrelated-table-using-hibernate)