# Loading Two Unrelated Entities (nothing in comman) in One Query [Spring Data JPA]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How can two unrelated entities , nothing in common be loaded in one Query using spring data jpa?

Current Code :

```
 User user = userRepo.findOne(userId);
 Post post = postRepo.findOne(postId);
```

This creates two sql query is there any way to do it 1 Query.

Is there any way doing like this

```
  Object[] userAndPost = someRepo.findUserAndPost(userId, postId);
```

Please note both user and post are unrelated and have no common column on which join can be done.

Sandeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822302/how-to-join-two-unrelated-entities-using-jpa-and-hibernate) and [this post](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) for a better explanation.

I have very little experience, but I've tested this code and it works for your particular case.

In the repo file (I'm using Spring boot):

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   @Query("select u, p from User u, Post p where u.id =:userId and p.id =:postId")
   List<Object[]> findUserAndPost(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("postId") Long postId);

}
```

And then, to test if that worked, you could try this code:

```
    List<Object[]> results = userDao.findUserAndPost(userId, postId);

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

        User user = (results.get(i)[0] instanceof User) ? (User) results.get(i)[0] : null;
        Post post = (results.get(i)[1] instanceof Post) ? (Post) results.get(i)[1] : null;

        // Do whatever with user and post...
    }
```

Comment: Great! It was my first answer ever, I'm glad it helped :)