# Use join to map user by id

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hql

I want to implement Join between tables:

```java
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String login;
}

@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transactions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 20)
    private Integer userId;
}
```

Using `login` I want to get to select the reference `id` from table `users` and map it to `userId` and list app rows which match the id from table `Transactions`.

I tried this HQL query:

```
SELECT c FROM Users u LEFT JOIN Transactions t ON u.id = t.id;
```

It's not clear to me how to select the appropriate `login` to `id`. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this thread: [How to join two unrelated entities using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822302/how-to-join-two-unrelated-entities-using-jpa-and-hibernate)

The top two answers show pretty well how to build your left join and what the implications are based on your version(s) of hibernate (i.e. whether you can or whether you must revert to SQL). Note you can expect each Row returned to contained one of both objects..

There are other ways you can map this relationship with lazy oneToManys and what not which you could entertain, but that would be beyond the scope of the question as asked.

As for where to filter on a user, it would be in your where clause.. i.e.

```
select ... WHERE user.id = transaction.user_id AND user.login = 'steve@minecraft.net';
```

Also unrelated but if your user_id *MUST* be on the transaction table, you might consider making it an "int" instead of an "Integer". Having it as "Integer" is more useful if it can be null (since unlike a primitive it can be set nullable).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to join `u.id` and `t.user_id`, rather than trying to join the transaction ID to the user ID. Since the transaction ID is probably just an integer that counts up, I don't think it's going to have anything to do with the user ID.

```sql
SELECT c FROM Users AS u LEFT JOIN Transactions AS t ON u.id = t.id;
```

I'm assuming the column `c` is some data field that you just cut out from your example, but if it isn't then it may also be complaining because it can't find a nonexistent column.

Comment: but I need to add also `where u.login = "some user"` I suppose? What is the proper way to add it?